# Array not following curve shape

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I have modeled a section of a wall. That section can be arrayed so that it looks like one seamless wall. I have an array modifier on the wall. I also have am uneven terrain. I have a curve that guides the wall. I have shrinkwrapped the curve so that it sits on the terrain. I expect the the wall to be on the terrain. Instead the wall is hovering in the air although the curve is doing what I expect it to do.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wall is not following the terrain because the curve has an unapplied modifier on it. You need to apply the shrinkwrap modifier to it. After you apply it the wall will follow the path like you expect.

[image]